# Getting exception jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript

Tags: jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting below exception

> bootstrap.js:240 Uncaught TypeError:  Bootstrap's JavaScript requires
>   jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript
>
> at Object.jQueryDetection (bootstrap.js:240) at bootstrap.js:255 at
>   bootstrap.js:9 at bootstrap.js:10

This is my code in `Angular.json`

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.css",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
],
"scripts": 
[
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"           
]
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Surely `"node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"` should come under "scripts"?

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.css",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
],
"scripts": 
[
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"           
]
```

And the now duplicated jQuery file `""node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"` should be removed.

Comment: Have you checked your file system to see that those file paths exist?

Comment: I made sure that jQuery and Bootstrap were properly installed into the project prior to adding these scripts. If jQuery is not installed you will get errors. The answer Kurt gave 100% correct.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use bootstrap in your application, or if you already have in your project, make sure to include jQuery before including the bootstrap JavaScript file. Bootstrap’s JavaScript file requires jQuery.

```
"scripts": [ "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
           "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"]
```

After including jQuery, stop running your Angular CLI application. Then, re-run it using `ng serve`.

And then, if you want to use jQuery in your code at some point, all you have to do is to import it in whatever component you want to use jQuery.

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

or

```
declare var $: any;
```